# [六月目]{むつきめ} meaning?

Tags: meaning, usage

I have been learning Nihongo for 1 month and I am confused with that word. Please help me!!

Comment: "confused that words"? Can you please tell us what (exactly) you don't understand (and what you do understand)?

Comment: i dont understand phrase word "六月目" meaning.

Comment: I'm surprised you're learning this word in your first month of Japanese.  Can you give us the sentence it appeared in?

Comment: The tutorial book gives me a simple sentense. It's here:
六月目に　なる。
六月目の　あさ。

Comment: They should teach more basic 六ヶ月目 first.

Comment: @user4092 小学校の教科書には「六月目」の方が先に出てくるようです。

Comment: そうですか、まぁ六ヶ月目は教える必要のない語彙ですからね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "more than 5 months have passed."

So

> "日本語を勉強し始めて[一月]{ひとつき}が経ちます。"

is the same as

> "日本語を勉強し始めて[二月目]{ふたつきめ}になります。"

Comment: Isn't it just "the 6th month"?

Comment: I don't think this post is so wrong as to be downvoted.